# Any pod and gem command results in "Invalid gemspec" error

Tags: flutter, rubygems, cocoapods

In my Flutter project, I installed some Firebase plugins and before running the app on an iOS device, I wanted to update CocoaPods.

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod setup
```

#### Report

- What did you do?

1. `pod repo update` -> successfully completed

```
Updating spec repo `trunk`
```

2. `sudo gem install cocoapods` -> successfully completed

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.11.2
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

3. `pod setup` -> the error occurred

- What did you expect to happen?
  I wanted to update CocoaPods by running the three commands above.
- What happened instead?
  After running `pod setup`, I got this error:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/cocoapods-1.11.2.gemspec]: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/cocoapods-1.11.2.gemspec:74: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
    end
    ^~~
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/cocoapods-1.11.2.gemspec]: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/cocoapods-1.11.2.gemspec:74: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
    end
    ^~~
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/cocoapods-1.11.2.gemspec]: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/cocoapods-1.11.2.gemspec:74: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
    end
    ^~~
```

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.x86_64-darwin21]
    RubyGems : 3.2.33
        Host : macOS 12.1 (21C52)
       Xcode : 13.2.1 (13C100)
         Git : git version 2.23.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

#### Error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1105:in `block in _latest_specs'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1102:in `reverse_each'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1102:in `_latest_specs'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1089:in `latest_specs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `plugin_gems_for_prefix'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:326:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

`flutter doctor -v` says:

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
      To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
```

After `pod repo update` -> `sudo gem install cocoapods`, any `pod` and `gem` command results in the same error, so I cannot run even `gem uninstall cocoapods` to reinstall CocoaPods. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved by deleting `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/cocoapods-1.11.2.gemspec`, in which the syntax errors occur.
This file would have collapsed when `pod repo update`d.

Then, I reinstalled cocoapods.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Also, I had to launch Android Studio from a console, resolving the PATH correctly.

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```